# ABPerson uses old picture data

Tags: cocoa, image

I have a Addressbook in my App which gets filled from a website by json. If I add a new Person on my website the person get added to the app addressbook on the next launch. If I update a persons name on my website it works perfectly.. but if I add a new image to a existing person it still shows the old default image from Apple after the reload. If I compile it the picture appears. Is there a cache for addressbook pictures?

I tried the following:

```
BOOL imgBool = ABPersonHasImageData(aContact); -> false
```

and

```
ABPersonRemoveImageData(aContact, &anError); -> false because no picture in AB
```

I add a Persons picture like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[self.profsInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] bildUrl]]]];
NSData *picData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9f);
[...]
ABPersonSetImageData(aContact, (CFDataRef)picData, nil);
```

There are no Errors, it just saves the last picture and ignores new pictures... :( Any ideas?

Comment: The new image url is always up to date in core data so json works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you forget to call saving function, after applying your changes in the address book?

```
ABAddressBookSave(addrBook, nil);
```

UPDATE: so, as long as you're using ABUnknownPersonViewController, I've tried the following code by myself and it's working both on the simulator & device

```
  ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();

  ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"Smith", nil);

  UIImage *personImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
  NSData *dataRef = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(personImage, 0.9f);

  CFErrorRef error = nil;
  bool result = ABPersonSetImageData(newPerson, (CFDataRef)dataRef, &error);

  ABUnknownPersonViewController *controller = [ABUnknownPersonViewController new];
    //controller.addressBook = addressBook;
  controller.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
  controller.displayedPerson = newPerson;

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
  [controller release];
```

The issue I've met when was testing this code, was my mistype in image name, so the `UIImage` instance was nil and `NSData` was empty. And `ABPersonSetImageData` gave no error on this. So, double check your `UIImage` instance is not nil.

Comment: I use the ABUnknownPersonViewController and just create and push it:

Comment: it works fine if it is hardcoded.. but if the db updates the old image stays for a while seems to be a cache for the addressbook.. didn`t change anything and it works now.. :(

Comment: If you're using ARC be sure to do a bridged cast: 


`bool result = ABPersonSetImageData(newPerson, (__bridge CFDataRef)dataRef, &error);`